# How can I fix the restriction violation of add-on triggers from time to time?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I created an add-on for Google Sheets that helps teachers create a variety of quizzes for their students. In my script code I used timed triggers:
To set the exam time for my students, I use the timeBased - everyMinutes trigger:

```
function stopFormRespones() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
for (var l = 2; l <= ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getLastRow(); l++) {
  var link = ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getRange('N'+l).getValue();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(link);
form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
}
}

function openFormRespones() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
for (var l = 2; l <= ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getLastRow(); l++) {
  var link = ss.getSheetByName('listStudent').getRange('N'+l).getValue();
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(link);
form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
}
}

function scheduledCollection(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var start = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F12').getValue();
  var end = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F14').getValue();
  var t = new Date();
  if (t > start & t < end) {
  openFormRespones();
  }
  else {
  stopFormRespones();
  }
}

function StartStop(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var start = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F12').getValue();
  var end = ss.getSheetByName('title').getRange('F14').getValue();
  var limit = ScriptApp.newTrigger('scheduledCollection')
              .timeBased()
              .everyMinutes(1)
              .create();
}
```

Since I have to create multiple Forms with the questions above, I have to use the timeBased - atHour trigger so as not to violate the function execution time quota:

```
function triggerMix() {
  var hour = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('title').getRange('AH7').getValue();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix1')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix2')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix3')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix4')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix5')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix6')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix7')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix8')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();

  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix9')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix10')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix11')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix12')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix13')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix14')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix15')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix16')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix17')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix18')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  var autoMix = ScriptApp.newTrigger('mix19')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hour)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}
```

All good. But when it was published, I did not know my project violated the add-on trigger restriction.
Specifically, the first trigger seems to be deleted (it doesn't work), and the rest of the triggers get an error message: "This add-on has created too many time-based triggers in this document for this Google user account ".
My question is:
Can anyone help me use some way to execute mix () functions without using triggers?
How else can I set the stopFormRespones and openFormRespones time?
Hope your help.

Comment: Do you have access to a computer with internet or a server? It would be used to do the automatic triggers from.

Comment: Sorry  Martí, I don't understand much, can you speak more clearly thank you!

Comment: I was asking if you can have a computer open. A server would also work. It would be used to execute the code. Because it's local, there would be no limits on quantity.

Comment: Another option is to try reduce the number of triggers necessaries, but I don't know how your code is organized. Why do you have functions called `mix1`, `mix2`, etc? It seems like they are the same function just changing some variables.

Comment: You are right, they are a function but the loop is so large that they exceed the allowed runtime. So I have to split it up and use the trigger from time to time. I also used the server to execute the code, it runs smoothly. However, if the screen turns off, it will stop working.

Comment: Could you add what a look looks like? If it's easy to make faster, it may be the easiest way of solving this.